# FOR XML EXPLICIT - need a smart way to query XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a complex XML structure I want to create from a single table in database. I managed to add like 5 different nodes as following:

```
SELECT 1 AS Tag
,NULL AS Parent
,NULL AS [Document-OrderResponse!1]
,NULL AS [OrderResponse-Header!2]
,NULL AS [OrderResponseType!3]
,NULL AS [OrderResponseNumber!4]
,NULL AS [OrderResponseDate!5]
,NULL AS [OrderNumber!6]
,NULL AS [DocumentFunctionCode!7]
,NULL AS [DetailsOfTransport!8]
,NULL AS [TermsOfDelivery!9]

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 AS Tag
    ,1 AS Parent
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 3 AS Tag
    ,2 AS Parent
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,'Type'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 4 AS Tag
    ,2 AS Parent
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,'Number'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT 5 AS Tag
    ,2 AS Parent
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,'Date'
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
    ,NULL
FOR XML explicit
```

The final document will be nested more and there are going to be around 15 more values. If i continue building the query like that, it will be a few pages long. Help me recreate it.

The result looks like this (without line breaks and indentation):

```
<Document-OrderResponse>
    <OrderResponse-Header>
        <OrderResponseType>Type</OrderResponseType>
        <OrderResponseNumber>Number</OrderResponseNumber>
        <OrderResponseDate>Date</OrderResponseDate>
    </OrderResponse-Header>
</Document-OrderResponse>
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to try a CLR procedure with the standard C# LINQ/XElement constructs to generate the output, assuming that's an option in your environment.

Comment: I'd rather not do that because I'm not experienced with these technologies. I guess its easily doable in SQL but Im missing something. Maybe I should put the data to different tables and use FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS?

Comment: `FOR XML PATH()` is your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try FOR XML PATH() instead.

Your query would probably look something like this:

```sql
select T.OrderResponseType,
       T.OrderResponseNumber,
       T.OrderResponseDate
from YourTable as T
for xml path('OrderResponse-Header'), root('Document-OrderResponse')
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain the opening XML tag if the data is an empty string? In that situation the XML looks like this </ABC> instead of <ABC></ABC>.

Comment: @ŁukaszKastelik it is really the same thing so it should not matter. Sometimes it is possible to coerce SQL Server into producing one or the other. Try adding `, type` to the end of the query.